# Accessing a certain variable inside a json without creating a deserialization class

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I currently have a json string that looks like this

```
{ 
   "strA":"somestr",
   "strB":{ 
      "strB":"String B",
      "strC":"String C",
      "sections":[ 
         { 
            "strD":"...",
            "str$":"...",
            "myArray":[ 
               { 
                  "name":"xxxx",
                  "value":"xxxx"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Now the content of this json could change however `strB` will always be where it is. The value of `strB` can always change. I would like to get the value of `strB` as string. I tried doing this

```
var info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(str);
string strB = info["strB"].ToString();
```

but that seems to be wrong . Any idea on how I can extract strB value from this json as a string without creating a deserialization class .

Comment: Sounds like you just want to use the raw [JObect](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm). You can use that to pretty much do exactly that.

Comment: I can also suggest looking at [JObject.Parse](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm) to parse the JSON into a `dynamic` and then access the `strB` property on it. You just need to do `dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(...)`

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm

Comment: You have a property named `"strB"` inside a property `"strB"` with the same name.  Do you want the inner or outer values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JObject` and run linq on it.

```
 JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonstring);
 // access the value like this
 json["strB"]
```

Find some very good example: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm